# No vimrc, gvimrc and .vim on mac

Tags: macos, vim

There are no `.vimrc`, `.gvimrc` files and `.vim/` directory on my mac, and so I can't install any script. And when I create a folder `.vim/` and `.vim/plugin` and paste any script in there, it doesn't work.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Could you enlighten us - how you went on? And what plugin you want to install? Easiest it would be to use tim pope's pathogen plugin to start with. (found at http://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) There you will find a detailed instruction how to install it and further plugins. short googelation finds this: http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?fromSeriesID=316&name=3160050

Comment: @epsilonhalbe
It didn't help. 
I trying [nerdtree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) with pathogen - and it is not works.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You *must* create those files and folder yourself:

1. Open Terminal.app (found under `/Applications/Utilities/`).
2. At the prompt, a `$`, type each of these lines followed by `<Enter>` (don't type the `$`):

   ```
   $ touch .vimrc
   $ touch .gvimrc
   $ mkdir .vim
   $ open .vim
   ```
3. At this point, the `~/.vim` folder is open in a new Finder.app window.

But I'd respectfully suggest you to get accustomed to the command-line *and* Vim's basics *before* rushing to install plugins.

***EDIT***

You didn't follow the instructions, no wonder the plugin doesn't work.

You have to move `cvim.zip` into `~/.vim` and run the command `$ unzip cvim.zip` in the terminal. Read the instructions more carefully and don't let Safari expand archives automatically.

Now that you have `~/.vim/c`, here is what you should do to go forward.

Supposing your `~/.vim` is empty (beside your `~/.vim/c`), move **the whole content** of `~/.vim/c` into `~/.vim`. After this operation, your `~/.vim` folder should look like that:

```
+ ~/.vim
   + c <-- your folder
   + c-support
       + (many folders and files)
   + doc
       + csupport.txt
   + ftplugin
       + c.vim
       + make.vim
   + plugin
       + c.vim
   + README.csupport
```

When you are done, delete `~/.vim/c` and start Vim. The plugin should be installed and working.

If your `~/.vim` folder is *not* empty (say it already has a bunch of folders and files like `~/.vim/color`, `~/.vim/syntax`, whatever…) you'll have to move *manually* each subfolder/file from `~/.vim/c` to the right place in `~/.vim`.

***ENDEDIT***

Comment: i just want to install [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213)

Comment: So, i did what you say, and after that a read a instruction to install [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213] "Copy the zip archive  cvim.zip to $HOME/.vim/ (Linux/Unix) and run 
unzip cvim.zip" i did it but  plugin didn't work.

Comment: How did you "unzip" cvim.zip? What do you get in `~/.vim` afterward? How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Safari unzip it instead of me. And i copy folder "c" in .vim. I know, that plugin didn't work because when i create a .c file there are nothing happens.

Comment: Please, see my edit. My advice to learn the basics of the command-line before you go any further still applies.

Comment: Also, i trying to install [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658). I followed your instruction, but it didn't worked. Please help with it too and i will go on lynda.com to learn terminal basics :)

Comment: I don't think the `unzip` command is available on Mac OS X. You should remember the whole process for next time. Just expand the archive somewhere and move the content of each subfolders in their correct location. You should get something like `~/.vim/plugin/NERD_tree.vim`, `~/.vim/doc/NERD_tree.txt` and `~/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/(some files)`. Mac OS X basics should be useful, too.

Comment: I did it, but 2nd plugin doesn't working. I scatter files in necessary folders. But command :helptags doesn't work, vim says: "E471: Argument required".

Comment: Didn't work. I input that, and nothing happened, inscription stay below but cursor go up. [screen](http://d.pr/i/DMZf)

Comment: That's not very user-friendly but yes, the command worked. Try `:help nerdtree`. All of that seems very basic to me. I don't know how it could go wrong or how I could explain it better.

Answer (score 7):

I found it on OSX Yosemite in /usr/share/vim/vimrc

Update: Unfortunately on OSX El Capitan, this file is no longer editable even via sudo.  So back to user-based versions in ~/.vimrc

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be as instructed by tim pope in the reference i gave
copy to your command line/terminal.app:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle; \
curl -so ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim \
https://raw.github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/master/autoload/pathogen.vim
```

also note if `curl` is not working try `wget -O - ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim`
put then into your `.vimrc`:

```
call pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

then unzip the plugin to `~/.vim/bundle/` in a folder of your choice 
and don't forget to do `:call pathogen#helptags()` in your vim after the installation to generate the documentation.

Comment: It didn't work. I did all what you say, but when i putting :call pathogen#helptags() vim just do nothing.

Comment: 1. did you do it in command or in insert mode, in general `:` means do this in command mode
2. vim should generate helptags in the background - your c-plugin should now work

Comment: Of course i did it in normal mode =/ C-plugin worked, but nerd tree didn't work. [screen](http://d.pr/i/OeRu)